# Нужно отсортировать строки в куче файлов

Tags: java

Дан список файлов содержащих кучу строк List files . Нужно отсортировать строки по длине каждого файла создав несколько потоков ,каждый поток будет сортировать часть файлов и списка

хочу ускорить работу сортировки разбив выполнение задачи на несколько потоков, но не могу понять , как сделать так , чтобы потоки не мешали друг другу

```
 private List<File> sortFiles(List<File> files) throws IOException {
    for (File f : files) {
        try (RandomAccessFile rand = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            String temp;
            while ((temp = rand.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(temp);
            }
            list.sort((a, b) -> a.length() - b.length());
            rand.seek(0);
            for (String s : list) {
                rand.write((s + "\n").getBytes());
            }
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

Comment: что-то не видно Вашего варианта развития событий

Comment: Тут можно увести в отдельный поток сортировку каждого отдельного файла, или вы хотите именно сортировку выполнять в несколько потоков?

Comment: именно каждый отдельный файл в отдельном потоке (я разбил 1 большой файл на кучу мелких и хочу их отсортировать , а потом слиянием записать в один новый файл)

Answer (score 0):

```
int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4; // сколько потоков использовать.
int WAIT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 60; // сколько ждать завершения сортировки всех файлов.

private List<File> sortFiles(List<File> files) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
    for (File f : files) {
        executor.submit(() -> {
            try (RandomAccessFile rand = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                String temp;
                while ((temp = rand.readLine()) != null) {
                    list.add(temp);
                }
                list.sort((a, b) -> a.length() - b.length());
                rand.seek(0);
                for (String s : list) {
                    rand.write((s + "\n").getBytes());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // файл не существует.
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // ошибка ввода вывода.
            }
        });
    }
    try {
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(WAIT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Не уложились в заданное время.
    }
    finally {
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
    return files;
}
```

Попробуйте так.